# gas fireplace pilot will not light

Tags: fireplace, pilot-light

My gas fireplace pilot will not light. It worked fine a few months ago until I shut if off.  My lighter has a knob which I turn towards pilot and hold pushed while I push the igniter button.

a few observations:
1.  I don't smell gas or hear anything when pushing in the knob to pilot
2.  Spark is visible

What can be causing this?

Thanks,